# How to find level of employee position using RECURSIVE COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
    ;with Ranked(Empid,Mngrid,Empnm,RN,level) As
    (select Empid,Mngrid ,Empnm ,row_number() over (order by Empid)AS RN , 
     0 as level from     dbo.EmpMngr),
     AnchorRanked(Empid,Mngrid,Empnm,RN,level)
     AS(select Empid,Mngrid,Empnm,RN ,level from Ranked ),
     RecurRanked(Empid,Mngrid,Empnm,RN,level)
     AS(select Empid,Mngrid,Empnm,RN,level from AnchorRanked 
     Union All
    select Ranked.Empid,Ranked.Mngrid,Ranked.Empnm,Ranked.RN,Ranked.level + 1 
     from  Ranked 
     inner join RecurRanked 
       on Ranked.Empid = RecurRanked.Empid AND 
         Ranked.RN = RecurRanked.RN+1)

select Empid,Empnm,level from RecurRanked
```

Comment: can you edit your question so that it is readable please

Comment: thnx  I WANT TO FIND THE EMPLOYEE LEVEL LIKE WHO COMES IN X 1,Y 2, Z 2 
A 3,B 3,C 4

Comment: THIS IS HOW I WANT THE OUTPUT

Answer (score 1):

This may help  [CTE Example of a simple hierarchy](http://blog.crowe.co.nz/blog/archive/2007/09/06/Microsoft-SQL-Server-2005---CTE-Example-of-a-simple.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH OrgChart AS 
(
   SELECT EmpID, EmpNm, [Level] = 0
   FROM EmpMngr
   WHERE MngrID IS NULL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT e.EmpID, e.EmpNm, [Level] + 1
   FROM OrgChart o
   JOIN EmpMngr e ON (e.MngrID = o.EmpID) 
)
SELECT EmpID, EmpNm, [Level] FROM OrgChart
```